# ARCHS[@]: Unbound Variable in Xcode 12.5

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am working on an iOS app using react native using Xcode 12.5. it's about a day I stuck in archive error:

`ARCHS[@]: Unbound Variable`

I tried all the solutions given in StackOverflow but no luck. i have attached my build settings here:

[image: My build settings on Xcode 12]

as I know the VALID_ARCHS has been removed from Xcode 12. Bulding works file but the archiving not i'm almost sure the problem is in the build settings.

I also tried:
[ARCHS[@]: unbound variable in Xcode 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474801/archs-unbound-variable-in-xcode-12)

and here is the error i'm getting:
[image]

anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: have you found any solution yet? I'm hitting the same error :(

Comment: Try with changing the Release to Any iOS simulator SDK and add arm64 like this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71145424/9372598