# Getting error line 132: ARCHS[@]: unbound variable

Tags: xcode, architecture

I have Xcode 13.2,
App Deployment target 12.0,
Swift version 4

Getting line 132: ARCHS[@]: unbound variable error while running in the real device. In the simulator, it is running fine.

I have also tried -

1. added arm64 in excluded architecture.
2. Build active architecture to Yes/No (no impact)

[Xcode Snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49hIP.png)

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71145424/9372598

Answer (score 6):

I added **$(ARCHS_STANDARD)** to the **"build settings > user defined > VALID_ARCHS"** setting in the project file and it was fixed. I hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Remove arm64 from the Excluded Architectures.

```
-Build Settings
  -Architectures
    -Excluded Architectures
```

Comment: This works, but only if there is not another pod or library that requires to add exclude arm64. It was my case. 

Yildiz answer worked in this case.