# PhaseScriptExecution Embed Pods failed when archiving on M1

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, apple-m1

I have an iOS project that is using cocoa pods. It used to work perfectly fine on intel architecture, but it is not working properly on my new M1 Mac.

First the project was not building/running on simulator, so I looked it up and figured that I have to set **Excluded Architectures** - **arm64** for both my app target and pods target, which I did and things started to work.

Now, when I try to archive the project I get the following error:

```
...ARCHS[@]: unbound variable
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I looked at some places and tried what people have suggested, but nothing seems to work for me yet. Here is what I've tried: [ARCHS[@]: unbound variable in Xcode 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474801/archs-unbound-variable-in-xcode-12)

I'm running Xcode 13.3 on M1 Pro.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem on my mac by deleting the derived data folder, on Library/Developer/Xcode. You don't need "Excluded Architectures - arm64", because it will create other problems for you.

Comment: I don't have Xcode folder in Developer folder, what to do?