# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code when running Unit Tests

Tags: ios

My project is in iOS native. When I run my Unit Tests this error is getting to me.
Otherwise it is working perfectly on my devices.

Please help me on it if there is any solution.

[image: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code]

Comment: Have a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474801/archs-unbound-variable-in-xcode-12

Comment: Thanks @Vikas, It is not hepful for me. Actually when run Unit Test without excluding arm64 it gives me an error in importing file as #import <Mantle/Mantle> file not found. When I excluded arm64 then I got this error as I mentioned.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].